# I am wondering why I keep getting an empty value in g-recaptcha-response post request

Tags: javascript, recaptcha, recaptcha-v3

```
 function onClick() {
        grecaptcha.ready(function() {
          grecaptcha.execute('Site-Key').then((token) => {
            document.getElementById("g-recaptcha-response").value = token;
          });
        });
      }
```

When I run this code I get an empty value, not sure why.

I have tried many things, tried getting a return token value and assigning it to my input as .value = token; I have also tried prepend(), setAttribute(), and many more. I am desperate as I am trying to implement reCaptcha v3. My code was running perfectly and all of a sudden it stopped working. I do get a response when I console log token, when I copy said log and attach it as value to hidden input it all works. So, I don't know why this code gives me an empty value.

Okay so when I run the code like this

```
grecaptcha.ready(function() {
          grecaptcha.execute('Site-Key').then((token) => {
            document.getElementById("g-recaptcha-response").value = token;
          });
        });
```

it works on my local host but not on my actual site. I have also tried

```
let captcha = () => {
  grecaptcha.ready(function() {
    grecaptcha.execute('Site-Key').then((token) => {
    document.getElementById('g-recaptcha-response').value = token;
    })
  })
} 
captcha();
setInterval(()=>{captcha();}, 110000)
```

and this also doesn't work :(